# Calling clear() on WeakReference is not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using a nested private static AsyncTask class in my Activity to do some work & I'm passing the Activity context to the AsyncTask & initialising it as a WeakReference.

After my work is done, in the `onPostExecute()`, I'm calling 

`if(mContext.get() != null) mContext.clear();`

but when I check in logcat whether `mContext != null`, it always returns `true`.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: @MayurGajra there's nothing fancy in the code, just a regular AsyncTask with a WeakReference to a Context

Answer (score 1):

I looked into some articles and some other stackoverflow answers,i came to a conclusion that you won't get `mContext == null` until and unless you assign null or the activity is finishing or has been destroyed before async task could complete the work.

So When you use `mContext.clear();` you do not make `mContext` null,you just clear this reference object and invoking this will not cause the object to be en-queued for GC.So you would only get `mContext.get() == null` true after you have clear the references as following.

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object object) {
            super.onPostExecute(object);
            if (mContext.get() != null) {
                mContext.clear();
            }

            Log.d("MG-Context", mContext.get() == null ? "Yes" : "No");
        }
```

Please have a look into this article here for better info:
https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/finally-understanding-how-references-work-in-android-and-java-26a0d9c92f83

Comment: that's what I said in my question, I cleared the reference like `mContext.clear();` & then checked whether it was null or not via Logcat, it was quite strange as it wasn't null where it should have been..